# Why corporate VPN requires "Forcepoint DLP" to access some port- not able to understand

Tags: networking, vpn, git

I am trying to access a site after connecting vpn, but getting an error as like this:

[image: port 22 connection timeout]

so, I could not get the git repo check outs. I tried to solve this, i got an answer to install "Forcepoint DLP Endpoint (8.5) "  is it really required? It's cost more. the url which blocking with vpn works fine without any issue in office.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you need special software.

What is more likely the issue is one of these:

- Your company blocks port 22 over VPN
- Your company blocks the domain or IP address over VPN
- There is a routing issue with your company's VPN (It's blocked, but not intentionally).

Does your company's own IT help to resolve this issue? Do not ask the IT for the VPN software; they didn't create this problem.

Comment: They only recommend to buy the software..?!